# Key set for ArrayCoreMap class

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am having trouble implementing the ArrayCoreMap class: I am having trouble setting a key with a value. This is what I have, but the compiler is showing an error:

```
CoreMap sentence = new ArrayCoreMap();
sentence.set("Dog", "Thomas");
```

I read the documentation of the API and this is what is says: `public <VALUE> VALUE set(java.lang.Class<? extends TypesafeMap.Key<VALUE>> key, VALUE value)`

So my question is what do I have to do to fix the error. I do not know how to use the `TypesafeMap.Key<VALUE>` to make my key. The API says this: "The classes that implement Key are the keys themselves - not instances of those classes." I do not know what the API means by this. What do I have to do to fix this error?

Comment: What error is the compiler giving you?

Comment: Its saying to rename the set() method? I think it is giving me this error because I am not inputing the correct method parameters

Comment: The quality of the question directly influences the quality of the answers. Provide the exact compiler error(s) that you're receiving and, if possible, link to the API you're trying to use.

Comment: This is the API link: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/TypesafeMap.html#set-java.lang.Class-VALUE-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set` method needs its first argument to a type that extends  `TypesafeMap.Key<VALUE>`, while your first argument is a `String`. Take a look [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/TypesafeMap.Key.html) to see the list of valid types. The key can, for instance, be `CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation` (implements `TypesafeMap.Key<String>`).

Comment: How can I make a sentence with ArrayCoreMap? I am trying to use the `RelationMention class`, which is going to be used in the `BasicRelationExtractor class` at the end of the day. The `RelationMention class` requires a `CoreMap sentence`, but I don't know how to make a sentence with a bunch of keys and values? Should not I just be able to put a string as a sentence?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It clears some stuff in my head

Comment: @user5139637 You are welcome. Your question about constructing  a sentence using `ArrayCoreMap` should be a separate question, not a comment.

Comment: Ok. I will make another question regarding this

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature of `set` method `set(Class<KEY>, VALUE)` where

```
<KEY extends TypesafeMap.Key<CoreMap,VALUEBASE>>
```

If you use below code it will compile successfully:

```
sentence.set(CoreAnnotations.SectionAnnotation.class, "Thomas");
```